# Perl mechanize multiple webpages in parallel

Tags: perl, mechanize, web-scraping

I have to fill out forms on multiple webpages. I am trying to fetch the data, parse the html into text, and store it in a single file. Every web form has different fields to be filled out; this is the code for one of them. I have three more. Suggestions are appreciated - thanks!

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 my $timeout=40;
 use WWW::Mechanize;
 use HTML::TreeBuilder;
 use HTML::FormatText;
 use HTML::Parser;
 use autodie qw/ open close /;
 use 5.012;
 use Win32::IE::Mechanize;
 use Time::HiRes 'sleep';
 my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);
 my $browser = Win32::IE::Mechanize->new(visible => 1);
 my $snp = "rs111";
 my $content= $browser->get("http://snp-nexus.org/index.html");
 my $html = $browser->content;
 $browser->form_name ('snpnexus');
 $browser->field('batch_text', 'dbsnp rs111');
 $browser->tick('ensembl', "ensembl");
 $browser->tick('refseq','refseq');
 $browser->tick('ucsc','ucsc');
 $browser->tick("sift",'sift');
 $browser->tick("polyphen",'polyphen');
 $browser->tick("chb",'chb');
 $browser->tick("chd",'chd');
 $browser->tick("tfbs",'tfbs');
 $browser->tick("consv",'consv');
 $browser->tick("gwas",'gwas');
 $browser->tick("indel",'indel');
 $browser->tick("mirbase" ,'mirbase');
 $browser->tick('gad','gad');
 $browser->tick('cnp' , 'cnp' );
 $browser->click_button('value', 'RUN');
 for (0 .. $timeout*20) {
 last if $browser->{agent}->ReadyState >=5;
 sleep 0.1;
 }
my $html2 = $browser->content;

 my $Format =HTML::FormatText->new();
 my $TreeBuilder =HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
 $TreeBuilder->parse($html2);
 my $parsed= $Format->format($TreeBuilder);

print $parsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Perl and Mechanize to submit a batch query. Their Guide page details how to submit a batch request for information using a tab delimited file.

http://snp-nexus.org/guide.html

Does that help? Quote:

> SNPnexus allows users to submit batch query when dealing with large numbers of variations. Users can either paste the variants list directly into the designed text space or upload a file containg the queries. Currently we limit the maximum number of variants in a single batch query to 100,000. We only allow batch query using genomic position and/or dbsnp rs# formats. No chromosomal region query data is allowed. Each variant must be on a new line with tab-delimited data in one of the following formats:

Comment: yes i can submit the text file but what i need is to use perl mechanize to make a web crawler so that i can navigate through multiple pages for single snp id in order to functionalize it. So i just want how can i modify my code to make it work for multiple webpages at a time. Thanks for your time